# AWK : Extract value between 2 html tag's' from an output which has html all in one line

Tags: bash, awk

I have an html output which is all in one line; i have tried to extract serial numbers using awk but for some odd reason I am only getting one output. The output from curl comes out as an xml format.

```
curl -sSku user:somepass https://somewebsite.com/computergroups/id/4
-X GET | awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;FS="<serial_number>|</serial_number>";RS=EOF} {print $2}'
```

the above command only prints the first occurance and ends there. It should print over several hundred.

Comment: Use something that understands XML to parse XML, not awk.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Shawn, I am specifically looking to use awk.

Comment: It's only reading one record, so there's only one `$2` parameter to print.  Maybe `RS` should be `</serial_number>`.  Then you could print `$NF`

Comment: Are the several hundred all on that same one line? If so you'll have to loop through every column in that one record with a for loop (in awk) and print out every even numbered column. I agree though that doing this in awk is a bit like trying to knit a sweater with a hammer.

Comment: i managed to find a tool that was helpful : so i first format it so that its not all in one line and then use awk:

`... | xmllint --format - | awk -F"[<>]" '/serial_number/ {print $3}'`

Comment: this should work: `awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;FS="<serial_number>|</serial_number>";RS=EOF} { s = s $2 "\n"} END {print s }'`

Comment: I'm not sure what you think `RS=EOF` is doing but what it's **actually** doing is puting awk into paragraph mode where each record is separated from it's neightbors by sequences of blank lines. It's doing that because `RS=EOF` is setting RS to the value of some undefined variable named `EOF` so it's the same as doing `RS=""`. If you're trying to read a whole file at one time and you have gawk (as you must have for IGNORECASE) then that'd be `RS="^$"`.

Answer (score 1):

if you have `gawk`

```
$ ... | awk -v RS='</?serial_number>' '!(NR%2)'
```

assumes open tag comes before close tag.

Comment: Yup, this is how to do it with gawk.

Answer (score 0):

Awk will be a fragile solution (i.e. would likely fail in the future if the output XML changes).

If you want to do it anyway just this once, use rs to knock each tag onto a line of its own and pick up the pieces after in awk with a regex.

```
$ echo '<serialnumber>098456</serialnumber><serialnumber>095444></serialnumber>' | rs -c\> 0 1
<serialnumber
098456</serialnumber
<serialnumber
095444
```

Comment: You are right, but this data will remain static until i am around :D

Answer (score 0):

Don't let anyone dismiss the power of `awk`, Khorem.

I generated some test data like this.

```
for n in {101..107}; do echo -n "a b c <serial_number>$n</serial_number>"; done > data
```

Then this,

```
cat data | awk -- 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;FS=">";RS="</serial_number"};/<serial/{print $NF}'
```

produces this.

```
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
```

Comment: Thanks Ken, this is just what i was looking for

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for multi-char RS and IGNORECASE.